# How should pass a DomCrawler object as input parameter correctly? "Undefined property: Crawler::$extract "

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

When I pass the DomCralwer Object to my helper function:

```
function extractText(Crawler $crawler, $selector)
{
    $result = $crawler->filter($selector)->extract['_text'];
    return $result ? $result[0] : false;
}
```

it can not recognize the `extract` method on it:

```
Undefined property: Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::$extract
```

Where is my problem?
I am quite new to `php` and `symfony`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling an extract method. Did you mean to use `('_text')` instead of `['_text']`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging whatever that `filter`  returns?